# loading txt files into excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have to load dozen of txt files from selected directory into an array or excel sheet.
The txt file structure is like below:

*

```
SST - 0010
Narzędzie - 08A38902
Miernik 0010  Nr seryjny = 90375091 Nr artykułu = 1010953
Moment obrotowy = 2,080 N.m Kąt obrotu = 5380,000 grd
Wartość zadana  = 5,000 N.m DG = 0,000 N.m  GG = 10,000 N.m
Kąt docelowy = 0,000 grd    Moment docelowy = 5,000 N.m
Wartość progowa = 0,200 N.m Wartość dokr. = 5,000 N.m
wartość KPIL = Wył. Czas martwy = 0,00 s    Współcz.nach. = > 1,00  Prędkość 
kątowa = 0,000
Cm =  2.42  Cmk =  1.04 Xpoprz =  2.15  
Czas [s]    Kanał 1 [N.m]   Kanał 2 [grd]
0   0,21    0
0,008   0,23    18
0,016   0,24    40,5
0,024   0,26    59,5
0,032   0,27    87,5
0,04    0,28    112,5
0,048   0,3 137,5
...
...
...
```

*

I have to load lines from row 14 to the EndOfFile.

The data are in 3 columns separated by tabulation. I want to copy the data into 3 excel columns for further purpose.

Each file schould be loaded into next set of columns.

If it's not a problem I prefer to use a button embeded in sheet to run the macro.

I really tried diffrent ways to do the task but I failed so I ask for your help :).

LAST time I've tried this code:

```
Sub LOAD_REAL_DATA()

Dim Filt As String
Dim FilterIndex As Integer
Dim Title As String
Dim FileName As Variant

Filt = "All Files (*.*),*.*"
Title = "Select a Txt File to Import"
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=Filt, Title:=Title)

If FileName = False Then
MsgBox "No File Was Selected"
Exit Sub
End If

With Application.ActiveSheet
    Cells.Select
Selection.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.ClearContents
End With

Workbooks.Open FileName
End Sub
```

I get "400 error" message...

With trhis code it is doing most of the work but there are some problems listed in comments under L42 reply.

```
Sub LOAD_TOOL_DATA()
Dim a, b, c As Integer
Dim TARFIL
On Error GoTo nofile
TEMPNAM = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
TARFIL = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", MultiSelect:=True)
'Set multiselect to true so you can select all file you want to load
b = UBound(TARFIL, 1) 'get the size of the array of files you just created
c = 1
'Loop through those files
Do
    Sheets("Arkusz1").Select
    a = 1
    'this loop is to ensure you do not copy same files
    Do
    Select Case Cells(a, 1).Value
    Case TARFIL(c)
        GoTo jump
    Case ""
        Cells(a, 1).Value = TARFIL(c)
        x = 1
    Case Else
    a = a + 1
    x = 0
    End Select

    Loop Until x = 1
    'this part opens the filename. In this case the txt file have 12 colums.
    ' if you have fewer columns then delete some Array(x,x) on the FieldInfo: part. You can also get this by recording Macro.
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=TARFIL(c), startRow:=14, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
    Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 1), _
    Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1))

    OPNFIL = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'this part specifies that it will only copy data from row 5 as indicated
    Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A:A")) + 1, 12)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(TEMPNAM).Activate
    Sheets("Arkusz1").Select
    Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A:A")) + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows(OPNFIL).Close
jump:
    c = c + 1
Loop Until c > b

Exit Sub
nofile:
'    MsgBox "No File Selected", vbInformation, "Load File Error"
End Sub
```

OK guys, this code works almost perfectly BUT: ;)

```
Sub LOAD_TOOL_DATA()
Dim a, b, c As Integer
Dim TARFIL 'Array for the file data
On Error GoTo nofile
TEMPNAM = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
TARFIL = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", MultiSelect:=True)
'Set multiselect to true so you can select all file you want to load
b = UBound(TARFIL, 1) 'get the size of the array of files you just created
c = 1
'Loop through those files
Do
    Sheets(8).Select
    a = 1
    'This loop is to ensure you do not copy same files
    Do
    Select Case Cells(a, 1).Value
    Case TARFIL(c)
        GoTo jump
    Case ""
        Cells(a, 1).Value = TARFIL(c)
        x = 1
    Case Else
    a = a + 1
    x = 0
    End Select

    Loop Until x = 1
    'this part opens the filename. In this case the txt file have 3 colums.
    ' if you have fewer/ more columns then delete/ add some Array(x,x) on the FieldInfo: part (where (x,x) is (column, row) index.
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=TARFIL(c), startRow:=14, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1))

    OPNFIL = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'this part specifies that it will only copy data from row 1 to EOF and from column 1 to 3
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A:A")) + 1, 3)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(TEMPNAM).Activate
    Sheets(8).Select
    Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A:A")) + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows(OPNFIL).Close
jump:
    c = c + 1
Loop Until c > b
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
nofile:
'    MsgBox "No File Selected", vbInformation, "Load File Error"
End Sub
```

- Multi file choice doesn't work,
- in target sheet in the first row it paste file path with the filename (I don't need that),

How to modify to select different target (other sheet and from cell address - lets say B9- to EOF)?

Comment: You can easily use the Macro recording option in Excel to record a macro of you manually loading the txt file using the "Import data" option in Excel. Once you have a macro, you can call it from a button.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: I tried that already- it wasn't working. I have sometimes more than 200 txt files to load. I can't do it all day. Like I wrote I have to load files from 14 row to EOL and split every column into different excel column. All of the rest I know how to do.

Comment: I make row 14 in your example `0,016    0,24    40,5`. Is that correct?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @Marshall777 
Variable names are in polish so you'll have a problem with understanding. Whats more I've deleted the code that didn't work. I don't have a manner to create many history files- it too messy for me...

Comment: @Alex P,
sorry my mistake. In this sample the start row is 12: 0   0,21   0

Comment: @ Sidhart Rout
I can implement some code but I don't like to put trash at a table. I tried to ask a clear questions without directing to not working solutions by showing wrong code.

Comment: @AndrzejJasienski [how to read *.txt files in VBA](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/)

Comment: @AndrzejJasienski and [how to iterate through all files in a folder in VBA](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/looping-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba/)

Comment: @mehow Btw thanks for the links, used them a couple of days ago to fill up a large excel table from a `.txt` file, an otherwise tedious task. Great job!

Comment: @meohow, thanks for the links, I've already bookmarked them :). 'll see what I can get from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY I have the code that works fast and elegant (for user):

```
Option Base 1

Sub LOAD_REAL_DATA()
'loading text files into excel sheet no 9. Every 3 columns are fixed next each other
Dim i, b, c As Integer
Dim TARFIL

On Error GoTo nofile
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
TEMPNAM = ActiveWorkbook.Name
TARFIL = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", MultiSelect:=True)
b = UBound(TARFIL, 1)
c = 1
i = 1
For i = 1 To b
    Sheets(9).Select
        Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=TARFIL(i), StartRow:=14, TextQualifier:=xlSingleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Space:=True
        OPNFIL = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A:A")) + 1, 3)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(TEMPNAM).Activate
        Application.Worksheets(9).Select
        Cells(1, c).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
    Windows(OPNFIL).Close
    c = c + 3
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
nofile:
    MsgBox "No File Selected", vbInformation, "Load File Error"
End Sub
```

Big thanks to you L42 for code sample which was a base for me. For Alex P thanks as well, unfortunatelly your code was too slow - I don't know why.

Basing on L42 code I've manage to create this one. Thanks guys!

Comment: this isnt fast... it uses select and copy which slow down the execution

Comment: @Andrzej, glad the code helped you. I still suggest that you include a tracker to make sure you do not load the same file twice. Also, include a handler or code which will handle files loaded with empty data. These two scenarios give me problems in the past.

Comment: @mehow, 15 files in 5 seconds is more than I've expected- so for me it's fast. Perhaps there are much faster methods but I won't need them for this application.
_L42, I'll see in the results of analysis from the data if any result is doubled. The same story with empty files. Once again, thanks for all for help and inspiration :) !

Comment: @AndrzejJasienski it may execute properly once or twice but logical errors happen all the time. at some point something will snap and will give you a hell load of problems because the script logic is broken ;]

Comment: @mehow, the data is analysed after loading. In the Analisis it is very visible if any identical result exists- which is very unlikely because of a experiments where the data is from. So this problem is secured - but not in the code. However, I apprieciate your concern. Can you give me some examples? It could be useful for the future...

Comment: two other answers :) im not saying yours is bad. As long as it achieves what you want it's infact a GOOD one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code that loads csv text file comma delimited.
See my comments which might help you get this working for you.
This loads all file content on sheet1 and put a tracker on sheet2 to ensure no duplicate date loaded.

```
Sub Load_File()

Dim a, b, c As Integer
Dim TARFIL

On Error GoTo nofile

TEMPNAM = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
TARFIL = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True) 'Set multiselect to true so you can select all file you want to load

b = UBound(TARFIL, 1) 'get the size of the array of files you just created
c = 1
'Loop through those files
Do
    Sheets(2).Select
    a = 1
    'this loop is to ensure you do not copy same files
    Do

    Select Case Cells(a, 1).Value

    Case TARFIL(c)
        GoTo jump
    Case ""
        Cells(a, 1).Value = TARFIL(c)
        x = 1
    Case Else

    a = a + 1
    x = 0

    End Select

    Loop Until x = 1

    'this part opens the filename. In this case the txt file have 12 colums. if you have fewer columns then delete some Array(x,x) on the FieldInfo: part. You can also get this by recording Macro.
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TARFIL(c), startRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
    Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 1), _
    Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1))

    OPNFIL = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'this part specifies that it will only copy data from row 5 as indicated
    Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A:A")) + 1, 12)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(TEMPNAM).Activate
    Sheets(1).Select
    Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A:A")) + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows(OPNFIL).Close

jump:
    c = c + 1

Loop Until c > b

Exit Sub
nofile:
    MsgBox "No File Selected", vbInformation, "Load File Error"

End Sub
```

The key here is how your already loaded text file looks like once you load it.
Then you can replace the codes above.

Comment: OK, thanks for the code. Unfortunatelly I don't know how to force the code to load the file just from row 12 to EOF. Secondly new workbook is created. How to direct the data to specific area in the specific worksheet (lets say from 'Torques'!C9 to EOF in 3 collumns)? Another problem that I see is that the data is not properly recognized, some numbers are not splitted in 3 collumns even if there is a tab between them... Don't know why. However this code is a good step forward.

Comment: New problems, It can open txt file only once and only in new sheet not in the one that is selected with the code...Some variable is not cleared in the loop? When I tried multi file choice it opened only first one that wasn't preaviously opened. All preaviously opened and all after first not opened were skipped.

Comment: it would help if you can post a snap shot on how your text file looks when loaded to excel. Is it the same for every text file or differs every time. if it is the latter, it will be hard to code a macro for it.

Comment: I cant post a snap- my rank is too low for now.       Multiselect doesn't working as well. Problem is persistent. 


I see that "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" is missing. Where to put that?

Comment: I moved the code to a module from worksheet. It resolve the problem with reopening the files and copying the data to prepared sheet instead of new one every time.=- += -= However there is new problem: instead of first data row it copies file path and next data rows to the EOF...

Answer (score 2):

Based on links from `Mehow` and other bits and pieces here is some sample VBA code that will:

1. Loop through all text files in a specified folder
2. Extract data from line 12 and above
3. Split it by tab and paste into a worksheet with each text file in new columns

I tested this based on a couple of text files and it worked for me. I am not sure how efficient it would be with 200+ files. Also, no error checking included.

```
Sub ParseTextFilesToColumns()
    Dim file As String, fileCount As Integer

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\MainFolder\" //Set your directory here
    file = Dir$(filePath)
    fileCount = 0

    While (Len(file) > 0)
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
        ReadTextFile filePath & file, fileCount
        file = Dir
    Wend
End Sub

Sub ReadTextFile(filePath As String, n As Integer)
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, inputLine As String, data As Variant, col As Integer, startLine As Integer

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading, False)
    startLine = 12 //get data from line 12 onwards

    Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
        inputLine = txtStream.ReadLine
        If txtStream.Line > startLine Then

            data = Split(inputLine, vbTab)
            col = (3 * n) - 2

            With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .Cells(txtStream.Line - startLine, col) = data(0)
                .Cells(txtStream.Line - startLine, col + 1) = data(1)
                .Cells(txtStream.Line - startLine, col + 2) = data(2)
            End With
        End If
    Loop

    txtStream.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I don't want to set any specific folder because it will be every time different folder for incoming measurements sets of files. At this point L42 code fits me better. However I'l try your code as well. maybe I can get sth from it...

Comment: I've tried the code but it doesn't seems to do anything... Nothing is going on...

Comment: Really? Have you tried debugging it by using the `Locals` window to see what is happening? Things to check: (i) `filePath` - is that set correctly; (ii) Are any text files found i.e. does the `While` loop run?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know how to debugg it. Is it possible that file path is too long? Mine has 145 characters... it looks like 2 procedures but wher is call from one to another?

Comment: I run Locals window without any succes, it remain empty. When I run ReadTextFile procedure it opent macros list windows (I don't know what for) and when I choose ParseTextfilesToColumns it does nothing as well...

Comment: You need to click the `ParseTextFilesToColumns` and hit `F5`. That's where the code executes from. `ReadTextFile filePath & file, fileCount` is the call to second procedure.

Comment: I did that. It didn't worked. The code is not in module but in the same sheet, can that be the problem?

Comment: Yes - put it in a module

Comment: Both procedures are in a module. Still nothing ... What has to be not OK for that kind of error?

Comment: I see that your code syntax is a bit different. I use Excel 2007, what excel do you use?

Comment: Excel 2010. Where are you getting stuck? For example does the `While` loop actually pass any text files to `ReadTextFile`? If so, does it ever execute `If txtStream.Line > startLine`? That's how to debug and find out where the issue is. I don't think the syntax is an issue.

Comment: It looks like this condition isn't working: `While (Len(file) > 0)`

Comment: In which case it is not picking up any text files at all from your specified folder. I'd check your file path etc.

Comment: I've copied file path from the code to windows explorer and it opens correct folder with correct files. So it looks like the path is not a problem... Maybe special characters in the path are the source of the problem? I'll try to test simple path without local characters in polish. Can you try the code in Excel 2007?

Comment: I've cut the path so it's really short now and doesn't contains any special symbols. I alco have copied the files into new folder. The problem is still the same. The code stops in the same point (`While`). Any suggestions?

Comment: AlexP, I got that, there was no "\" at the end of the path. Now there is a different error: "Compile error: User-defined type not defined". Locals windows says: that in ReadTextFile procedure has missing some variable...

Comment: `Dim fso As FileSystemObject` is highlighted as well.

Comment: Try adding `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in `References`

Comment: I think that helped, but it seems to work wery slow. 3 files (not very big) were loaded in 3 minutes. Can that be improved?

Comment: I've added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False/ True` in the code so now it works a bit better. How to update the code so user could select directory from window not by changing the code?